# regex to replace or separated list

Tags: javascript, regex

User can input an OR or AND separated keywords in an input box for searching. 
I need to take the keywords and replace it with the app query string required to perform the search.

**Example 1**

User Input

```
ThiS or That or That one
```

**replace it with**

```
[fieldName] like 'ThiS%' OR [fieldName] like 'That%' or [fieldName] like 'That one%'
```

I need to do this using javascript **replace** function

Comment: Do you need the OR/AND to be upper case in output and lower case in input, or does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using capturing group:

```
var pattern = /(.+?)(\s+or\s+|\s+and\s+|\s*$)/ig;
'ThiS or That and That one'.replace(pattern, "[fieldName] like '$1%'$2");
// => "[fieldName] like 'ThiS%' or [fieldName] like 'That%' and [fieldName] like 'That one%'"
```

- `([\w\s]+?)` matches word/space (non-greedy). -> group 1
- `(\s+or\s+|\s+and\s+|\s*$)` matches `or`, `and` or trailing optional space at the end of string. -> group 2
- The entire pattern matches word(s) followed by `or`/`and` or at the end of the string.

**UPDATE**

If you want escape special characters:

```
var pattern = /(.+?)(\s+or\s+|\s+and\s+|\s*$)/ig;
'Th_iS or T"hat and Th%t one'.replace(pattern, function($0, $1, $2) {
    return "[fieldName] like '" + $1.replace(/(['"_%\\])/, '\\$1') + " %'" + $2;
});
// => "[fieldName] like 'Th\_iS %' or [fieldName] like 'T\"hat %' and [fieldName] like 'Th\%t one %'"
```

Comment: Why do you only allow `\w\s` as possible search terms?

Comment: @JosephMyers, To match multiple words.

Comment: But what if someone wants to search for "part-time"? Your code would only include "time" as the search term, because a hyphen is not included in the list of characters matched by `\w` (an underscore is, but not a hyphen).

Comment: @JosephMyers, Then, replace `[\w\s]` with `[-\w\s]`.

Comment: A hyphen is just one example, however.

Comment: @JosephMyers, Do you mean I should use `.` instead of `[\w\s]`?

Comment: As you wish. There is danger in a `.` as well. Perhaps `[^'\\]` would be safer than `.`, just to make sure there aren't any nefarious quotes inserted into the generated query string, and the same for backslashes. (At this point, I don't know if the OP is even interested in our detailed discussions...)

Comment: @jospeh yes, I am intrested. Answer given by you works but this seems to be more concise form but unfortunately it doesn't  matches every type of string as pointed by you. I will try with your last suggestion.

Comment: @Neel, I updated the answer to use `.+?`. Also added another code that escape some special characters like `'`, `"`, `_`, `%`,   Escape method varies according to your choice of DBMS. Change as your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateQueryString(input) {
    return (input + ' or ')
        .replace(/\\|'/g, '')
        .replace(/\s*(.*?\S)\s+(or|and)/ig, "[fieldName] like '$1%' $2 ")
        .replace(/\s+or\s+$/g, '');

}
```

Please note that keywords or search phrases containing conflicting `'` marks could be used for code injection, and the same for search terms containing backslashes (at minimum). Those two characters are being removed from input ahead of time.

Also, I'm adding an `/i` flag because I believe the input should be case insensitive. Some users might type in or and some OR.

Call the function like this

```
queryString = generateQueryString("ThiS OR That AND That one");
```

Produces this: `[fieldName] like 'ThiS%' OR [fieldName] like 'That%' AND [fieldName] like 'That one%'`

Comment: Is it possible to do it without splitting and also how to handle AND?

Comment: OP said `User can input an OR or **AND** separated keywords`

Comment: The code yields `"[fieldName] like 'ThiS OR That AND That one%'"` unlike the last sentence in the answer.

Comment: Wrong: `[fieldName] like 'ThiS%' or [fieldName] like 'That%' and [fieldName] like 'That one%'`

Comment: OP specified user input of lower case "or." Adding an `i` flag was your idea. The OP did not specify that. If you add an `/i` flag to mine, you'll get what you are getting.

Comment: @JosephMyers, I didn't specified `i` flag in  the code (in the ideone code).

Comment: @JosephMyers, BTW, OP did not mentioned about any lowercase. Actually the example in the question include both `OR` , `or`.

Comment: Exactly!!!! That's why you are getting the wrong results, because you are separating your input with capitalized letters, when the OP specified lowercase. If you want to use your varying case of input, then you need to specify the `i` flag.

Comment: That is because the OP gave all lower case "or" in the input. I am going by his specification, not yours. If he wants to have case-insensitive input, then he can add the `/i` flag after the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant with regexp

```
"ThiS or That or That one".replace(/(.+?)((?:or|and)(.+?))|(.+)/gi, 
         function(a,b,c){
             return '[fieldName] like \''+(b||a).trim()+'%\' ' + (c||'');
         })
```